# Instead of next and previous arrow, Is it possible to show the next and previous slider image in bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using a bootstrap 4 image carousel slider for my website. I tried the below code and it's working.

Now What I am doing is, Instead of next and previous arrow I have to show the next and previous slider image. Is it possible?

This is an previous arrow example. I have to display the image instated of arrow.

Example
[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(45).jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(46).jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(47).jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite carousel class and set your own css on next and prev images

try this code

```html
   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(45).jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(46).jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(47).jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<style>
     .carousel-control-prev-icon{width: 100px;height:250px;}
     .carousel-control-next-icon{width: 100px;height:250px;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    var next_src = $('.carousel-inner .active').next().find('.d-block').attr('src');
    var prev_src = $('.carousel-item').last().find('.d-block').attr('src');
    $('.carousel-control-prev-icon').css({"background-image": "url('"+prev_src+"')"});
    $('.carousel-control-next-icon').css({"background-image": "url('"+next_src+"')"});
    $('#carouselExampleFade').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
        var next_src = $('.carousel-inner .active').next().find('.d-block').attr('src');
        if(next_src == undefined){
            next_src = $('.carousel-item').first().find('.d-block').attr('src');
        }
        var prev_src = $('.carousel-inner .active').prev().find('.d-block').attr('src');
        if(prev_src == undefined){
            prev_src = $('.carousel-item').last().find('.d-block').attr('src');
        }
        $('.carousel-control-prev-icon').css({"background-image": "url('"+prev_src+"')"});
        $('.carousel-control-next-icon').css({"background-image": "url('"+next_src+"')"});
    })
</script>
```

if you want to use background image as slide then use this jquery code

```
var next_src = $('.carousel-inner .active').next().css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace('")','').replace('"','');
var prev_src = $('.carousel-item').last().css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace('")','').replace('"','');
$('.carousel-control-prev-icon').css({"background-image": "url('"+prev_src+"')"});
$('.carousel-control-next-icon').css({"background-image": "url('"+next_src+"')"});
$('#carouselExampleFade').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    var next_src = '';
    if($('.carousel-inner .active').next().length > 0){
        next_src = $('.carousel-inner .active').next().css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace('")','').replace('"','');
    }else{
        next_src = $('.carousel-item').first().css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace('")','').replace('"','');
    }
    
    var prev_src = $('.carousel-inner .active').prev().find('.d-block').attr('src');
    if($('.carousel-inner .active').prev().length > 0){
        prev_src = $('.carousel-inner .active').prev().css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace('")','').replace('"','');
    }else{
        prev_src = $('.carousel-item').last().css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace('")','').replace('"','');
    }
    $('.carousel-control-prev-icon').css({"background-image": "url('"+prev_src+"')"});
    $('.carousel-control-next-icon').css({"background-image": "url('"+next_src+"')"});
})
```

Comment: OP question => *Instead of next and previous arrow I have to show the next and previous slider image.*

Comment: @DilipPatel, You change the arrow image. I need slider image so that user can view my next image

Comment: @user9437856 You want next img in replacement of an arrow ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, Check my description, I added example with a screenshot.

Comment: @user9437856 do you want slider like this link?
https://materializecss.com/carousel.html

Comment: @DilipPatel, I updated another image in the description. Please check it.

Comment: @DilipPatel, apologise for the late reply.Yes i was talking about this. Give me some time to implement this answer with my code.

Comment: @DilipPatel, Yes it's working. I just want to know if I use background image then what script I have to change it? 
something like this <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(45).jpg')">

Comment: @DilipPatel, Please find the code here https://jsfiddle.net/56tmrg30/

Comment: @DilipPatel, Thank you so much, it's working as my expected. Upvote from my side

Comment: @DilipPatel, I need your small help in this code. This code is working perfectly on y home page but when I click on about page then I am getting the error in console Uncaught TypeError: $(...).next().css(...) is undefined. can you help me in this?

Comment: @DilipPatel, Can you help me?

Comment: @user9437856 did you include jquery in this page or can you send me link?

Comment: @DilipPatel, I am working on local, I don't have server access. I added a script on the main.js file which is common for all the pages. The slider is working there is no issue with slider. I added the HTML code on the home page but I am getting the error on about and remaining pages because var next_src  and var prev_src  are not getting the image

Comment: @user9437856 then you can check if length of $('.carousel-inner .active') is greater then 0 then you can run the code

Comment: @DilipPatel, Ok So I have to use if( $('.carousel-inner .active').length>0 ){ // script code herr } right?

Comment: @user9437856 yes

Comment: @DilipPatel, Yes, It's working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding the functionality is not supported by bootstrap, but you can approach this with adding a custom class to your carousel and then using css to add a background image to the arrows

So for example:

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade
```

Will become:
<a class="carousel-control-prev carousel-back-arrow" href="#carouselExampleFade

In this line here you can add carousel-back-arrow into the class attribute, then you can add a  tag in the header.

Inside you can then style your custom class

```
.carousel-back-arrow { background-image: url(path-to-your-image); background-size: contain; }
```

You can read about classes here:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp
Here you can see an example of image inside elem with css:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-an-image-url-to-your-div/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you help me little bit example how to start with custom class?

Comment: I think I can understand 5/10.

Comment: Let me check. Give me sometime

Comment: Hi, Yes, I checked your code but If I add a background image as you assist me then I will get only two static images, I have to show the slider images.

Comment: Ah okay I see, well you could use jquery to accomplish that, so every time the slider image changes you get the prev and next image urls and then set the style background-image to the corresponding arrow divs

Comment: Yes, Can you help me with jquery?

Comment: Im just heading to sleep but tomorrow sure if noone will help you before that

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can display previous & next image in sliders with arrow mark by using **bootstrap carousel**

check the demo link i mentioned here, i hope it will useful for you

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/daLzpL

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="item__third">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=1" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="item__third">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=2" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="item__third">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=3" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Yes, I checked that before uploading the question. That's not working for me. Can you help me with my example?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this code & refer my screenshot too

[your images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p82Xa.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' class=''>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>CodePen Demo</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-aec34940fbc1a6e787974dcd360f2c6b63348d4b1f4e06c77743096d55480f33.ico">
<link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-8f3771b1072e3c38bd662872f6b673a722f4b3ca2421637d5596661b4e2132cc.svg" color="#111">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/daLzpL">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style class="INLINE_PEN_STYLESHEET_ID">
    .show-neighbors {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.show-neighbors .carousel-indicators {
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
.show-neighbors .carousel-control-prev,
.show-neighbors .carousel-control-next {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 11;
  /* .carousel-caption has z-index 10 */
}
.show-neighbors .carousel-inner {
  width: 150%;
  left: -25%;
}
.show-neighbors .carousel-item-next:not(.carousel-item-left),
.show-neighbors .carousel-item-right.active {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
}
.show-neighbors .carousel-item-prev:not(.carousel-item-right),
.show-neighbors .carousel-item-left.active {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
}
.show-neighbors .item__third {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  /* captions can now be added */
  width: 33.33333333%;
}

  </style>
<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/editor/iframe/iframeConsoleRunner-7f4d47902dc785f30dedcac9c996b9f31d4dfcc33567cc48f0431bc918c2bf05.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/editor/iframe/iframeRefreshCSS-e03f509ba0a671350b4b363ff105b2eb009850f34a2b4deaadaa63ed5d970b37.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/editor/iframe/iframeRuntimeErrors-29f059e28a3c6d3878960591ef98b1e303c1fe1935197dae7797c017a3ca1e82.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bd-example">
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide show-neighbors" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item active">
<div class="item__third">
<img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(45).jpg" alt="First slide"" class="d-block w-100">
<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
<h5>First slide label</h5>
<p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<div class="item__third">
<img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(46).jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
<h5>Second slide label</h5>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<div class="item__third">
<img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(47).jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
<h5>Third slide label</h5>
<p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-157cd5b220a5c80d4ff8e0e70ac069bffd87a61252088146915e8726e5d9f147.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script id="INLINE_PEN_JS_ID">
    $('.carousel-item', '.show-neighbors').each(function () {
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
}).each(function () {
  var prev = $(this).prev();
  if (!prev.length) {
    prev = $(this).siblings(':last');
  }
  prev.children(':nth-last-child(2)').clone().prependTo($(this));
});
    //# sourceURL=pen.js
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I updated example  and expected output in the question.

Comment: then check this example(Demo2) & let me know http://www.menucool.com/jquery-slider

Comment: No, Not like that. full image and instated of arrow I have to show sider image

Comment: provide me full output screen for your requirement, like how i added in my another answer. your added image vertically showing, its not clear.